# Shall we use "Have" or "had"

Tags: grammar

> "They’ve worked there for three years but they still got sacked" or 
>   "They'd worked there for three years but they still got sacked"

(I had read the first version in the article but I don't know why the second text was not used)

Comment: Present Perfect (your first version) implies great ***immediacy, relevance to time of utterance*** than Past Perfect (the second). So you'd be very unlikely to use the first version if they were sacked several years ago, but you might well use the second in that context. Note that *they **got** sacked* is a somewhat downmarket / colloquial alternative to standard *they **were** sacked*.

Comment: And if I use "are" intsted of "were" then what would it mean

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You *didn't* use "were" anywhere in your question text (and it's not easy to see where you *could* have). I suppose a few native speakers might say *They’ve worked there for three years but they're still sacked / they still **get** sacked*, but it would be a fairly unusual way of amplifying the "relevance to time of utterance" implications of Present Perfect. And it's *extremely* unlikely they'd use that form after the **Past** Perfect (that would be a really confusing mixture of tense-based time references), so I suppose you could say that's a "difference".

Comment: I don't understand any of your comments. Does my first comment answer your question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are okay; however, the context is *somewhat* different.

> The ***have*** worked there for three years but still got sacked

the event is quite recent. We may call it a *recent past.*

> The ***had*** worked there for three years but still got sacked

the event is quite old. It is a *distant past.*